# HTML use width and height dimensions for sections

Tags: html, css

I am working on my own website and I am quite new to HTML. Now I got following code:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
h1{
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:50%;
  text-align:center;
  
}
.block1,
.block2,
.block3,
.block4,
.block5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block1 {
  background: deeppink;
}

.block2 {
  background: Crimson;
}

.block3 {
  background: LightSeaGreen;
}

.block4 {
  background: aqua;
}

.block5 {
  background: lightsalmon;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="block1">
  <h1>
 Sample Text 
  </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="block2">
  </section>
  <section class="block3">
  </section>
  <section class="block4">
  </section>
  <section class="block5">
  </section>
</body>
```

Now my question: Is it possible to use in e.g. `block3` the dimensions like `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. So with that I am able to treat every section just like the first where I can properly use width and height.
I guess it would be possible to go for like `300%` for the lower sections but that seems to be quite dirty.

Comment: The `<section>` tag is a block-level element by default. So you can certainly use `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` on it, as is demonstrated in your above snippet. And yes, you can use a height greater than `100%` (the percentage is relative to the **parent** -- `<body>`). But perhaps you would benefit from `vh` height measurements, which are in relation to vertical viewport? Other than that, I'm afraid I struggle to see what your problem is.

Comment: Use `div` instead of `section`. Use `margin: 0 auto` to center things and use `width:100vw` and `height:100vh` to create `div`s that are the size of the viewport. See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/qpwhmkof/)

Comment: My problem is how to get for each section individual percents. Means that for example in the second block/section I want to say "<h1 style="width:50%,height:50%" and then its centered in the SECOND block.
I do know how to center things. Sorry if my post was misunderstandable.

Comment: In that case use `position` and `translate` like so : https://jsfiddle.net/ukLw1x5o/

Comment: This one seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using absolute positioning on an `<h1>` element, and also trying to centralise the text there. You need to apply `text-align: center` to the **parent** element, and use **relative** positioning in order to centralise text.

Having said that, in order to centralise text **both** vertically and horizontally, the easiest way is to use **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**. All you need to do is set `display: flex` on the `section`, and set `margin: auto` on the text elements:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
}

.block1 {
  background: deeppink;
}

.block2 {
  background: Crimson;
}

.block3 {
  background: LightSeaGreen;
}

.block4 {
  background: aqua;
}

.block5 {
  background: lightsalmon;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="block1">
    <h1>
      Sample Text
    </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="block2">
    <h1>
      Sample Text 2
    </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="block3">
    <h1>
      Sample Text 3
    </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="block4">
    <h1>
      Sample Text 4
    </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="block5">
    <h1>
      Sample Text 5
    </h1>
  </section>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of extra HTML and CSS here.

1. Body takes height of its content by default and your blocks are going to take more than 100% of screen so no need for setting `height: 100%` for `html, body`.
2. Setting here for `width: 100%` is useless.
3. You can set `height: 100vh`, just for every `section` and `height: 50vh` for last.
4. Also no need for `h1`, you can center plain text inside flex-container, plain text will be treated as anonymous flex-item.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  /* become a flex-container */
  display: flex;
  /* center flex-items vertically */
  align-items: center;
  /* center flex-items horizontally */
  justify-content: center;
}

.block1 {
  background: deeppink;
}

.block2 {
  background: Crimson;
}

.block3 {
  background: LightSeaGreen;
}

.block4 {
  background: aqua;
}

.block5 {
  background: lightsalmon;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="block1">
  <h1>
    Sample Text
  </h1>
</section>
<section class="block2">
  <h1>
    Sample Text 2
  </h1>
</section>
<section class="block3">
  <h1>
    Sample Text 3
  </h1>
</section>
<section class="block4">
  <h1>
    Sample Text 4
  </h1>
</section>
<section class="block5">
  <h1>
    Sample Text 5
  </h1>
</section>
```